# EthersJS returns array double wrapped i.e [ ["0x838383...", "0x3BC2...", ] ]

Tags: solidity, web3js, arrays, ethers.js

I have a method that is supposed to return an array of deployed contract addresses, it works albeit the value that is returned client side is wrapped with an extra set of brackets and also when checking its type on the client side with `typeof deployedInstances` is shows `object`.

```
clonedAddresses[] public contractAddresses;

function getContracts() external view returns (clonedAddresses[] memory) {
    return contractAddresses;
}
```

and the client side JS looks like this

```
const instance = new ethers.Contract( contractAddress, abi, signerObject );  

let deployedInstances: any = await instance.functions.getContracts();
```

The data being returned to me looks like this  `[ ["0x838383...", "0x3BC2...", ] ]` what I want is a simple 1 dimensional array which I can run forEach or map on, when i run forEach on this as it is it just dumps out all the addresses as a string.

Update in response to below question:

```
    [
        [
            "0x78dfd733877590257B00185879879B18698C4395",
            "0x637016b704d143b875f05e03406740Bc91757881",
            "0x5C5068504f3032d7D3e3a6750C31790a00CA95F4",
            "0x3bcA495aAdE569F1357a46e304f6D246061C2F2b",
            "0xba8D7BeFBC6de94D835F5C976057b2E36980375c",
            "0x489335Fd18cD4ade0dCCf70F729a6456E1dFE1C8",
            "0xC0718A6aD60228C2a8e6D5b4074013579E024d43"
        ]
    ]
```

Comment: Please `console.log(JSON.stringify(deployedInstances, null, 4))` and tell us what you get.

Comment: @goodvibration sure, just added the output above

Comment: So use `deployedInstances[0]`.